# Migrating from google calendar api v2 to v3 - Client Authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I coded a desktop calendar application a while ago, based on an existing database for an older calendar.
A bit later I added functionality to interact with google calenders using the v2 api, that is deprecated for a while now. Functionality might brake in november: [Deprecation Policy](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol) ..so I thought it's about time to update to the v3 api.

What my calendar application does related to google calendar:

Writing/Reading in a shared google calendar
Writing/Reading in own (multiple) private google calendars
Syncing private/shared google calendars into an own database.

In v2 it was pretty easy to login to any calendar having the credentials with the [GoogleDataApi](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin)

```
CalendarService calService = new CalendarService("MyCalendar");
calService.setUserCredentials(account, password);
```

and then reading, writing, update events.

In the v3 api theres no clientlogin anymore, how would I proceed with oauth2 to achieve the same functionality? How would I let a user login from my desktop application to his google calendars, so he is able to sync/view/edit/add google events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating is a good idea! For v3 you should take a look at Oauth2 for desktop app (you will need to get and store Oauth2 access token and a refresh token for your users to not need the user to re-enter their credentials). The calendar documentation for this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth
The generic Oauth2 documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp
Some more documentation from drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth
And the most useful of all, the playground to try stuff out: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: figured it out, tbh I just tried to migrate my code, without testing how the new authorization works, hadn't in mind, that the known google login box in browser will open, to login the user.